# Is it possible multi-database call for YII2 or LARAVEL 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, yii2

I'm developing a big project by using YII framework ( MySql database engine ). I'm preparing to continue developing the rest part of the project by migrating to YII2 or Laravel 5.
In this my question I'm not asking which one frameworks is better, because it is clear there no unambiguous answer and it is better if you try both by your self.
Because the rest part is related with archiving the data and generating the reports over archives for me very important question is if some one of these frameworks lets multi-database calls in one query - something as sample below:

```
SELECT * FROM database01.table1 t1, database02.table2 t2 WHERE t1.id1=t2.id2;
```

And if this is possible I prefer if it can be done without ORMs
From light research I've done I understood that for YII2 it is possible, but only by using Active Records - it's ORM implementation. Sadly but for LARAVEL 5 I can't find the answer - I have a feeling it can, but it is only feeling by looking on some samples.
So please give me your advice!
And one more time - I'm not asking for advice which one framework is better, because I'm preparing to test them by my self. I was happy with YII and of course I'll extend to YII2, but what I'm reading for LARVEL also is great, I simply like to choice which one will be the first one and learn and try along completing the current project.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Orms are built on top of such sql statements, so it's always possible to do it without the orm.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are talking about relationships in Laravel? http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships

Comment: Probably it is an answer too, but also ORM - right?

Comment: @Robert Harvey you are right on principle but can you show me how it will be done on YII2 - part of database configuration file and mainly how you'll call your query in DAO behavior?

Comment: Follow the link that ceejayjoyz put in his answer

Comment: @Robert Harvey - Thanks to you, I've done it. I've looked on this documentation before but It isn't exactly clear - I've needed the notes made by ceejayouz - now I'm sure it is the answer I'm seeking for. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel allows [direct database queries](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#running-queries).

For example, `$results = DB::select('SELECT * FROM database01.table1 t1, database02.table2 t2 WHERE t1.id1=t2.id2');` would execute your sample query and give you an array of results.

Comment: can you show me part of configuration of DB-links for this example?

Comment: @KanchoIliev This will use the credentials in `config/database.php`. You'll need a MySQL user with access to both databases. Since you're explicitly stating which database to connect to in the query itself, the value of `database.connections.mysql.database` will be irrelevant - but you could set it to the most frequently accessed database so you can just do `SELECT * FROM table1` against it.

Comment: @ceejayouz this one was the article I've observed before - it was that gave me feeling it is possible in Laravel. But the note for using named connections disappointed me because I thought they must - for that I've need advice of Laravel developers. In case you've used it - this is my answer. Thanks to you very much!